# Find Right USB Stick by Volume label in XP by Batch

Tags: batch-file, find, label, windows-xp

```
for /f %%D in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find "ALP"') do set usb=%%D
```

Wmic hasn't got volume function in on XP prof. How can use this code in XP I will use %%D for copy some files to right USB stick if I can find right USB by label.

I use that code on win7 but it don't work on xp

Answer (score 0):

This should work in XP and above.

```
@echo off
set "driveletter="
for %%a in (d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    if exist %%a:\nul (vol %%a: |find /i "ALP" >nul && set driveletter=%%a)
)
if defined driveletter copy "your files" "d:\target"
```